# Reading Git config variable using NodeGit

Tags: node.js, git, nodegit

NodeGit does not seem to be providing any API to retrieve Git configuration values.

See http://www.nodegit.org/#Config

I was expecting something like Config#getValue() or similar API to retrieve configuration values.

Perhaps, it is missing in NodeGit as of now, since libgit2 has those APIs.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeGit currently doesn't [expose the config functionality](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/fd6fc3151c1b7ad6946c5dfd300051a1a786cbc8/generate/input/descriptor.json#L334-L451) of libgit2. That shouldn't be too hard to get in there but I don't know if it'll make into the 0.3.0 release that is scheduled for the next release.

I created an [issue](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/449) that you can track if you want updates on the progress of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to get a global git config variable:

```
var nodegit = require("nodegit");

nodegit.Config.openDefault()
  .then(function (config) {
    return config.getStringBuf('user.name');
  })
  .then(console.log);
```

and here's how to get a repository's config variable:

```
nodegit.Repository.open('PATH_TO_REPO')
  .then(function (repository) {
    return repository.config();
  })
  .then(function (config) {
    return config.getStringBuf('user.name');
  })
  .then(console.log);
```