# Is there a way to set git configurations with nodegit?

Tags: node.js, nodegit

Getting git configurations was answered in this post [Reading Git config variable using NodeGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806392/reading-git-config-variable-using-nodegit) but is there a way to **set** git configurations using nodegit?